# JSON Deserializing list of lists

Tags: json, vb.net, list, tuples, deserialization

I have a problem deserializing the following JSON string:

> {"error":null,"id":1234,"result":[[["config.param1","111"],["config.param2","1222"]],"Config System",1234]}

My structure is:

```
 Public Structure stuConResponse
  Dim [Error] As String
  Dim ID As String
  Dim Result As List(Of stuSubResults)
 End Structure


 Public Structure stuSubResults
  Public Property X1 As List(Of List(Of String))
  Public Property X2 As String
  Public Property X3 As String
 End Structure
```

And my code is:

```
  Dim JSonSettings As New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
  JSonSettings.CheckAdditionalContent = True
  JSonSettings.DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.DateTime
  JSonSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
  JSonSettings.FloatFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.FloatFormatHandling.DefaultValue
  JSonSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore

Dim HeloResponse As Structures.stuConResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Structures.stuConResponse)(ReceivedData, JSonSettings)
```

I tried making "Results" the following:

1) A tuple of (list of (list of (string), string, string))

2) A list of (list of (string))

3) Other lists and tuples combined

For the life of me, I can't deserialise the "result" object whatsoever.

I have no problems reading the error and ID, but when Result comes in, I get the error that JSON can't do it.

I don't also mind if "result" can go into a string un-deserialised where I can do some manual logic, but that also don't work as JSON is trying to be too cleaver.

In other words, the problem is getting JSON to read "[[[X1,Y1],[X2,Y2],X3,X4]", notice that it's a list/array and that it does not have any Key-names which is where the problem is (I think).

It would be great to get your thoughts on this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it!, I had no idea that you can use IDICTIONARY to read the whole thing and then break it down into ILISTs...

For anyone who is having the same problem, here is the solution:

1) Code:

```
  Dim I As Integer
  Dim ConPolConfig As Structures.stuConPolSubscribeResponse = Nothing

  Dim dicItems As IDictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IDictionary)(ReceivedData, JSonSettings)
  ConPolConfig.ID = dicItems("id")
  ConPolConfig.Error = dicItems("error")

  If Not dicItems("result") Is Nothing Then
   ConPolConfig.ConfigItems = New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))

   Dim ConfigProperties As IList = dicItems("result")(0)
   Dim ConfSysReader As String = dicItems("result")(1)
   Dim Token As Integer = dicItems("result")(2)

   Dim ParamKey As String
   Dim ParamVal As String

   Dim Dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

   For I = 0 To ConfigProperties.Count - 1
    ParamKey = ConfigProperties(I)(0)
    ParamVal = ConfigProperties(I)(1)

    Dic.Add(ParamKey, ParamVal)

    ConPolConfig.ConfigItems.Add(Dic)
   Next
  End If
```

2) Structures:

```
Public Structure stuConPolSubscribeResponse
 Dim [Error] As String
 Dim ID As String
 Dim ConfigItems As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))
End Structure
```

This works and does exactly what I am looking for as per my initial question. i.e. reading a list or lists where the master list has an additional 2 different elements (a string and an integer). the iDictionary would read the whole thing without any errors and then you could iterate it using an ILIST...

Don't ask me why the source JSON string is written in such a way... but now this works to read it...

... I need a coffee ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim JSONC = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(yourjson)
 Debug.Print(JSONC("result")(0)(0)(0)) 'get result collection, then first element, then first object then first element of object
```

You decide what you want to do with the object.

You can convert ii to dictionary then get stuff with ("key") but if the data stays the same I see no point.

Comment: Hi CruleD, Thank you for replying, The system is crashing at DeserializeObject, therefore your debug.print would not be reached. Also, you are using a Java library, whilst the code above is about NewtonSoft JSON with some VB.NET code. My initial query was about finding a way to stop it from crashing, anyhow, I solved it below.

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization ' for easier reading of JSON (+the reference to System.Web.Extensions library). Though it should be the same regardless which one you use.